# When I concatenate via cat file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt file3.txt can't print

Tags: linux

I have file1.txt and file2.txt.  file1.txt is invoices and file2.txt is the summary file.  I want to concatenate the two into file3.txt using

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

When I do this, there are 5 invoices, I can only print the first one, the other 4 don't print, nor does the summary print.  The files got concatenated but now it isn't printable. I use VIPP in these files which is a Xerox product(language) which basically is just instructions on how to print the file.  Here's a sample of the invoice file:

```
%XRXbegin: 001.200
%XRXtitle: Storage_Tank_Invoice
%XRXrequirements: duplex
%XRXdisposition: PRINT
%XRXend
%!
%%DocumentMedia: perf 612 792 0 tanks (perf)
(FX271907_INV.jdt) STARTLM
1109-40665
1123559
1162589
1112/04/2014
11john doe1
11some road
11some city, state, zip
11
11925522
11$125.00
11$0.00
11$125.00
11john doe1
11some company
11some road
11some city, state, zip
11
11
11925522
1112/04/2014
1109-40665
11
1102/04/2015
11    610293  001A      15,000  DIESL  02/2015-02/2016  $125.00
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11$0.00
11$125.00
111
111
%%XGF (FX271907_COM.jdt) SETJDT
HD
HD
HD
TX
TX
TX
TX
%%EOF
(FX271907_INV.jdt) STARTLM
%%XGF(FX271907_INV.jdt) SETJDT
1115-39645
11603430
1162589
1112/04/2014
11john doe2
11some road
11some city, state, zip
11
11925341
11$125.00
11$0.00
11$125.00
11john doe2
11some company
11some road
11some city, state, and zip
11
11
11925341
1112/04/2014
1115-39645
11
1102/04/2015
11    953497  001A      10,000  DIESL  02/2015-02/2016  $125.00
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11$0.00
11$125.00
111
111
%%XGF (FX271907_COM.jdt) SETJDT
HD
HD
HD
TX
TX
TX
TX
%%EOF
(FX271907_INV.jdt) STARTLM
%%XGF(FX271907_INV.jdt) SETJDT
summary file txt1
summary file txt2
summary file txt 3
summary file txt 4
%%EOF
```

Comment: Are there some VIPP tools that make it possible to merge documents?

Comment: I don't know.  I'll check.  Thanks.

Comment: having multiple `%%EOF` seems dicey. Hand edit your file to remove any but the last. Does that solve your problem? If so, then you should look at `sed` quiestions so you can figure out how to delete all `%%EOF`s but the append one at the end of all files. Good luck.

Comment: Yes you're right, and that does work I found out Friday if I take the extra %%EOF's out.  Now if I can do it programmatically(ie. through a shell script) that would be much better.  If you have any commands you know of that would be much appreciated.  If not, thanks for your help!

Comment: yes, `sed '/%%EOF/d' file1 file2 > file3 ; echo "%%EOF" >> file3` might do it. Learn to reply like @shellter and then users will see your replies as you make them ;-) .Good luck.